# JQuery Toggle Navigation Bar Using Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So I'm trying to make my navigation bar toggle using JQuery however when I click on the span button, nothing is happening.

HTML

```
       <div id="navbar">
        <span class="navbar-btn"></span>
        <ul>
            <li class="currentpage"><a href="/Unit20/Photographer/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

JQuery

```
    <script>
        $('span.navbar-btn').click(function() {
            $('#navbar').toggle();
        });
    </script>
```

Live Version can be found at http://joshscottonthe.net/Unit20/Photographer - Just rescale your browser less than 960 pixels and you should see the button

Comment: Make sure the script is executed after the DOM is loaded. For example using [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include your script after the document is loaded.

```
$(function() {
  $('span.navbar-btn').click(function() {
    $('#navbar').toggle();
  });
})
```

Or you can include it in the same way you did, just make sure that the `<script>` tag is placed after that `<span class='navbar-button'>`.

Comment: Ahh, I had the script at the top of the page just below the opening body tag, that was what caused the issue then as it works now that I placed it just above the closing body tag. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2):

I think this should solve the problem:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('span.navbar-btn').click(function() {
                $('#navbar').toggle();
            });
            });
```

Comment: I added this at the bottom of the page and it works, thanks a lot.